# Will ApproximateReceiveCount get increased when lambda failed to process SQS message?

Tags: aws-lambda, queue, amazon-sqs

I have a queue (standard) and a lambda trigger and a DLQ. I configured maxReceiveCount as 5. I have to do certain operation when lambda processing the same message 5th time. Can I depend on `ApproximateReceiveCount` attribute from message object?. [From AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueAttributes.html), I assumed like when a lambda failed to process a message from queue then it will try until the maxReceiveCount reaches and then the message will be moved to DLQ. Can anyone let me know my assumption is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that assumption is correct. The `ApproximateReceiveCount` is not be relied upon. Maybe you can explain a little bit more about what you are trying to accomplish then I can provide some guidance.